# R Packages for own penalized Regression Matrix

Tags: r, regression, mgcv

I want to do a multivariate regression. I have y, which is a matrix, and one vector x, which is my predictor variable. I want to do a multivariate regression while penalizing the coefficients I get. Something like:
`$||y-xb|| + \lambda b^t P b $`
But I have a "own" penalty term which I want to use for penalized regression. When I searched for penalized regression, I found a lot of packages but all of them have predefined penalties like lasso, ridge or second differences.

I used the `gam()` package in mgcv when I had a univariate response:

```
gam(Y~x_1, paraPen = penaltymatrix)
```

but this package do not support multivariate regression.

Is there any R package where I can use an individual penalty matrix with my coefficients? Or can you give me any advice on how to solve the problem I have?

Comment: You can do it in tensorflow/keras.  Define the cost function and perform some form of gradient descent.

Comment: Thanks for your Anwser. Never worked with tensorflow/keras before. Isn't there any R package similar to mgcv for multivariate response variables?